# looking for help with base rigging a game model

Tags: animation, rigging

i am looking for help trying to set up a custom made skeleton for a game unit (For xcom 2) that i have made the concept sculpt for, but my skills with setting up something like that are more or less non existing as i am very new to stuff like this.
I have done custom animations before / edited existing animations and i know how to add custom / more bones to existing skeletons

examples of some of my animations here
https://streamable.com/khmug
https://streamable.com/jpcw0

so i am thinking I got this part down (somewhat)

the model i sculpted is here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRo2S.jpg

i have tried on and off for a few months trying to set up a rig for this but have to admit i actually dont have the skill to do that yet..

anyone in here that would be able to provide some guidance on how you would set this up for animations?

Answer (score 1):

- It looks like you might need to start with some re-topology or a decimation modifier first. Lower the poly count so the engine can cope with your model, if it's not for a rendered cut scene that is.
- Next Add some bones, the first bone must be created in
  object mode (Tab), add a armature bone (Shift + A, A, S).

  To keep the bones visible in front of your mesh, select a bone then go to the
  Properties panel, Object Data tab, Display drop menu, TICK In Front.

  In edit mode: Extrude bones (E), Parent bones (Ctrl + P), Clear Parent Bones (Alt + P) 
  or
  add bones (Shift + A).
- Parent the object (mesh) to the armature (Bones): Select the object, and the armature together 
  (Shift + LMB) and parent them with automatic weights (Ctrl + P, I).

Comment: - Weight paint the object, so that the bones effect the correct vertices.  
- Pose the armature, to test your geometries deformation.  
- Animate in pose mode, 3D view & Time Line windows.

Comment: I already have low poly version of this mesh..

My issue is i am having a really hard time figuring out where to put bones / how to create the mesh from scratch to give it the best movement 

i have done bone additions to other skeletons before that work just fine, but its just the first hurdle of creating a good skeleton that will make animating this the easiest i have the problem with

Comment: Bones should follow the mass and be central to it, but your blob would need a tripod like setup, each bone pointing to the contact points it will drag its self from in movement, additional bones pointing up for different parts to wobble independently on top.  For the mesh check out human elbows, knees and shoulders, how the mesh is setup for deformation and the results they bare. Basically only add more geometry where it needs to bend more and cut the geometry into loops strips so unwrapping is more consistant